# all links redirecting to old domain after moving to new domain

Tags: database, redirect, base-url, domain

we moved the site from one domain to another domain

after moving, admin panel working fine.

but in frontend, except the home page, every page/link is redirecting to the old domain.

means categories and products links are also redirecting to old domain

please help me to find solution

Comment: Did you check your server configuration?

Comment: we moved site which in is vps to the site in shared hosting

Comment: we are using shared hosting. what and things need to look from server side?

Comment: @RajeevKTomy thanks for your comment, but there all pages, but here only home page is fine.

Comment: I guess you reindexed everything and cleared cache already?

Comment: have you checked your DB in config_data table and made sure your site points to your new domain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you change your domain in your DB?

Check: core_config_data

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%base_url%';
```

This will return two rows at least, one for secure and the other for unsecure base url. You need to update this to your new domain.

Also flush the cache.

Comment: i changed in core_config_data , but still the same issue.

Comment: Did you check DNS? Also check your apache/nginx config, maybe the routing there is not updated

Comment: we moved site which in is vps to the site in shared hosting

Comment: the site which we moved has CDN.... is this affects too ?

Comment: Yes this could be an issue, check the http request for images, css, and so on if they are going to the old domain, if yes then you need to update this

Comment: thanks for your support. i edited new site name in database file , finally its worked...

Comment: @lloiacono I am cloned my localhost Magento, but still redirect old localhost url not redirect to new localhost url, how can i solve this issue. I am trying your idea, it's not working

Answer (score 2):

Another issue could be simple browser redirections that are also cached.

Comment: tried in another system, but same problem....

Comment: But you did the 3 things you should do on every problem? clear cache, reindex , clear cache and after that use a browser in incognito mode?

Comment: thanks for your support. i edited new site name in database file , finally its worked...