# Transfer magento 2 to new domain, links redirect to old one

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

We have a dedicated server managed with **whm** and **cpanel** for the domains.

I have created a `dev version` for my **magento 2** website https://domain.com.

I have uploaded `files` and `database`, changed 
in **core_config_data** table for `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` to have the new domain *dev.domain.com*.

Now the issue is the new domain has links who redirects to the old domain, in the top navigation, menu, account creation link, ...

The original website is multistore website with 3 stores with mode developper activated

When viewing the new domain firstime i got session error, i fixed it adding 
'save_path' => '/tmp'

```
'session' => [
 'save' => 'files',
 'save_path' => '/tmp', 
],
```

**In app/etc/env.php**

In the original website, there’s no problem related to session, is adding this config causes a problem?
I cleared cache folder var/cache

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf /var/tmp/magento/*
```

, also with this command

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

also removed static files

```
rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml pub/static/frontend
```

Reindex links

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

But always menu and top navigation links are from the old domain
I tried this question [all links redirecting to old domain after moving to new domain](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/73362/78366) and this [Moved magento to new domain, admin URL redirect to old admin URL](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/71476/78366) but without a solution.

Edit in I added this code to get base url in module-theme Topmenu.php file

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
var_dump($storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl());exit;
```

It returns the old website

Comment: As you have mentioned the website is multistore, there will be multiple values as per scope_id in core_config_data for path web/unsecure/base_url. Just make sure you change all store values instead of changing for only default scope.

Comment: @YashShah it is fixed when i changed the web/secure/base_link_url to the new domain

Answer (score 2):

Try these commands

```
 1. rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
 2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the old domain for different stores in app/etc/env.php